# Qt message box displaying at the left corner in the Debian linux

Tags: linux, qt, debian, x11

I have Issue, when I run the application on host machine Linux 12.04 the Qmessage box is displaying at the center and same application compiled for the linaro device then running on Debian OS displaying the Qmessage box in the Left corner.

Please help me on this. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Giving MainWindow (or one of its descendant) as **a parent** to your QMessageBox should resolve the problem. The child will be centered on his parent.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the desktop manger used in the Debian.

With the flux box the Qt Message box is displaying in the left top corner.

I have installed OpenBox desktop manager [ Based on Blackbox, with various features including anti-alised fonts with Xft and Xinerama support for multiple monitors] and the problem solved. :)

Comment: Ok, so it was not a Qt problem. Great if OpenBox solved it :)

Comment: it is working properly in the Host machine, displaying in the middle of the application, but only when I run in the X11 debian OS I am facing this issue.

Comment: I can't help for that point, I don't have enough experience with that. Sorry.